# Insert a file in Google Drive without parentId in Java

Tags: java, google-drive-api

For uploading a file to a specific folder in the Drive, I understand that I have to set the parameter parentId in the following method:

```
  File body = new File();
  body.setParents(Arrays.asList(new ParentReference().setId(parentId)));
```

Now, is there a way to use a different parameter? My problem is that when I retrieve the resources from a specific folder in the Drive with my Gson parser, the parentId property is always null. Why is that happening? Do I have to set the Id when I upload it? What if I create the folder directly in the drive.google.com site? Other parameters like title or dateCreated are working fine though.

Many thanks.

Edit: I added some code to show what's going on.

```
MyJson.java

@SerializedName("parentId")
private String parentId;

@SerializedName("createdDate")
private String createdDate;

public final String getDateCreated(){
return this.createdDate;
}

public final String getParentId(){
return this.parentId;
}

Main.java

public static String[] jsonParser(String jsonText){

Gson gson = new Gson();

    JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();

    JsonArray Jarray = parser.parse(jsonText).getAsJsonArray();

    ArrayList<MyJson> lcs = new ArrayList<MyJson>();

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    //Please ignore this Stringbuilder is just for testing purposes
    for(JsonElement obj : Jarray )
    {
        MyJson cse = gson.fromJson( obj , MyJson.class);
        lcs.add(cse);
    }

    List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();

    for(MyJson j: lcs){
        strings.add(j.getTitle() ); 
        sb.append(j.getParentId() + " " + j.getDateCreated()); 
    }

    System.out.println(sb.toString()); //Here it prints out null+date


    String[] arr = strings.toArray(new String[strings.size()]);

    //When I print this array shows the title perfectly
    return arr;

}
```

This is the text resource that I'm passing to the previous method.

```
[[{"alternateLink":"https://docs.google.com/folderview?id=0Byylok4NwwGOR2VTX1JOb1BnNDg&usp=drivesdk","appDataContents":false,"createdDate":"2013-07-25T06:17:20.228Z","editable":true,"etag":"\"RFvxxXV9yoZniidCHgcusodAlXI/MTM3NDczMzA0MDIyOA\"","iconLink":"https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/doclist/images/icon_11_collection_list.png","id":"0Byylok4NwwGOR2VTX1JOb1BnNDg","kind":"drive#file","labels":{"hidden":false,"restricted":false,"starred":false,"trashed":false,"viewed":false},"lastModifyingUser":{"displayName":"Luis Manuel Lavieri","isAuthenticatedUser":true,"kind":"drive#user","permissionId":"13217068352953415214","picture":{"url":"https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-yNHuP50oJzI/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAIQ/Wv4lZdE3FyU/s64/photo.jpg"}},"lastModifyingUserName":"Luis Manuel Lavieri","mimeType":"application/vnd.google-apps.folder","modifiedDate":"2013-07-25T06:17:20.228Z","ownerNames":["Luis Manuel Lavieri"],"owners":[{"displayName":"Luis Manuel Lavieri","isAuthenticatedUser":true,"kind":"drive#user","permissionId":"13217068352953415214","picture":{"url":"https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-yNHuP50oJzI/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAIQ/Wv4lZdE3FyU/s64/photo.jpg"}}],"parents":[{"id":"0ACylok4NwwGOUk9PVA","isRoot":true,"kind":"drive#parentReference","parentLink":"https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/0ACylok4NwwGOUk9PVA","selfLink":"https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/0Byylok4NwwGOR2VTX1JOb1BnNDg/parents/0ACylok4NwwGOUk9PVA"}],"quotaBytesUsed":"0","selfLink":"https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/0Byylok4NwwGOR2VTX1JOb1BnNDg","shared":false,"title":"Web Design","userPermission":{"etag":"\"RFvxxXV9yoZniidCHgcusodAlXI/Rok55oKCdYb_mqyTjquQPLiUiIg\"","id":"me","kind":"drive#permission","role":"owner","selfLink":"https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/0Byylok4NwwGOR2VTX1JOb1BnNDg/permissions/me","type":"user"},"writersCanShare":true}, {"alternateLink":"https://docs.google.com/folderview?id=0Byylok4NwwGORzhjODJPeVVUYXM&usp=drivesdk","appDataContents":false,"createdDate":"2013-07-25T06:17:10.835Z","editable":true,"etag":"\"RFvxxXV9yoZniidCHgcusodAlXI/MTM3NDczMzAzMDgzNQ\"","iconLink":"https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/doclist/images/icon_11_collection_list.png","id":"0Byylok4NwwGORzhjODJPeVVUYXM","kind":"drive#file","labels":{"hidden":false,"restricted":false,"starred":false,"trashed":false,"viewed":false},"lastModifyingUser":{"displayName":"Luis Manuel Lavieri","isAuthenticatedUser":true,"kind":"drive#user","permissionId":"13217068352953415214","picture":{"url":"https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-yNHuP50oJzI/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAIQ/Wv4lZdE3FyU/s64/photo.jpg"}},"lastModifyingUserName":"Luis Manuel Lavieri","mimeType":"application/vnd.google-apps.folder","modifiedDate":"2013-07-25T06:17:10.835Z","ownerNames":["Luis Manuel Lavieri"],"owners":[{"displayName":"Luis Manuel Lavieri","isAuthenticatedUser":true,"kind":"drive#user","permissionId":"13217068352953415214","picture":{"url":"https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-yNHuP50oJzI/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAIQ/Wv4lZdE3FyU/s64/photo.jpg"}}],"parents":[{"id":"0ACylok4NwwGOUk9PVA","isRoot":true,"kind":"drive#parentReference","parentLink":"https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/0ACylok4NwwGOUk9PVA","selfLink":"https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/0Byylok4NwwGORzhjODJPeVVUYXM/parents/0ACylok4NwwGOUk9PVA"}],"quotaBytesUsed":"0","selfLink":"https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/0Byylok4NwwGORzhjODJPeVVUYXM","shared":false,"title":"Finance","userPermission":{"etag":"\"RFvxxXV9yoZniidCHgcusodAlXI/Hsb4mdHUJCfDZwXE6ivhuygOXig\"","id":"me","kind":"drive#permission","role":"owner","selfLink":"https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/0Byylok4NwwGORzhjODJPeVVUYXM/permissions/me","type":"user"},"writersCanShare":true}, {"alternateLink":"https://docs.google.com/folderview?id=0Byylok4NwwGOa1E5Zng1dTVpZ0U&usp=drivesdk","appDataContents":false,"createdDate":"2013-07-25T06:17:00.482Z","editable":true,"etag":"\"RFvxxXV9yoZniidCHgcusodAlXI/MTM3NDczMzAyMDQ4Mg\"","iconLink":"https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/doclist/images/icon_11_collection_list.png","id":"0Byylok4NwwGOa1E5Zng1dTVpZ0U","kind":"drive#file","labels":{"hidden":false,"restricted":false,"starred":false,"trashed":false,"viewed":false},"lastModifyingUser":{"displayName":"Luis Manuel Lavieri","isAuthenticatedUser":true,"kind":"drive#user","permissionId":"13217068352953415214","picture":{"url":"https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-yNHuP50oJzI/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAIQ/Wv4lZdE3FyU/s64/photo.jpg"}},"lastModifyingUserName":"Luis Manuel Lavieri","mimeType":"application/vnd.google-apps.folder","modifiedDate":"2013-07-25T06:17:00.482Z","ownerNames":["Luis Manuel Lavieri"],"owners":[{"displayName":"Luis Manuel Lavieri","isAuthenticatedUser":true,"kind":"drive#user","permissionId":"13217068352953415214","picture":{"url":"https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-yNHuP50oJzI/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAIQ/Wv4lZdE3FyU/s64/photo.jpg"}}],"parents":[{"id":"0ACylok4NwwGOUk9PVA","isRoot":true,"kind":"drive#parentReference","parentLink":"https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/0ACylok4NwwGOUk9PVA","selfLink":"https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/0Byylok4NwwGOa1E5Zng1dTVpZ0U/parents/0ACylok4NwwGOUk9PVA"}],"quotaBytesUsed":"0","selfLink":"https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/0Byylok4NwwGOa1E5Zng1dTVpZ0U","shared":false,"title":"Marketing","userPermission":{"etag":"\"RFvxxXV9yoZniidCHgcusodAlXI/1meV_djX_pEtNrpJb1GQPQAT5hw\"","id":"me","kind":"drive#permission","role":"owner","selfLink":"https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/0Byylok4NwwGOa1E5Zng1dTVpZ0U/permissions/me","type":"user"},"writersCanShare":true}]]
```

I know that there are various types of ids there, and not what I'm looking for (parentId, folderId) but how should I do if I wanted to insert a file in the "Web Design" folder? How can I set those Ids? What should I do with the null values?

Comment: May I get where is parentId being set in the code?

Comment: It seems like the main problem is "when I retrieve the resources from a specific folder in the Drive with my Gson parser, the parentId property is always null". Could you share the code where you retrieve resource from specific folder?

Comment: Sure, I just edited the question and added what seemed to me the source of the problem. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Just like you are setting the parent, with a list of parent objects, you should read it in the same way.

```
"parents": [
  parents Resource
],
```

Not parentId.

Comment: Thanks. How should I read that list? I'm not sure how to do it. Why does it work with the title and other parameters? The tutorial mention a parentId. That's why I was trying to do it that way.